Why won't Cognito send custom email message templates in the AdminCreateUser case?
I have a Cognito custom message handler, trying to send customised messages on creation of a new user
It works fine except that whilst Cognito will send my custom email subject, it won't send my custom email message body, preferring its own default version instead
I can't work out why, and can't find a way to ask Cognito why either :/
Here's my handler code
import logging, os

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def replace_placeholders(message, attributes):
    for key, value in attributes.items():
        message = message.replace(f'{{{key}}}', value)
    return message

def validate_placeholders(message, required_placeholders):
    for placeholder in required_placeholders:
        if f'{{{placeholder}}}' not in message:
            raise RuntimeError(f"Missing required placeholder: {{{placeholder}}}")

def handler(event, context):
    # START TEMP CODE
    logger.info("Event [START]: %s", event)
    # END TEMP CODE
    user_attributes = event['request']['userAttributes']
    code_parameter = event['request']['codeParameter']
    username_parameter = event['request']['userAttributes']['email']
    attributes = {**user_attributes,
                  'codeParameter': code_parameter,
                  'usernameParameter': username_parameter}
    if event['triggerSource'] == 'CustomMessage_AdminCreateUser':
        email_subject = os.environ['TEMP_PASSWORD_EMAIL_SUBJECT']
        email_message = os.environ['TEMP_PASSWORD_EMAIL_MESSAGE']
        required_placeholders = ['usernameParameter',
                                 'codeParameter']
    elif event['triggerSource'] == 'CustomMessage_ForgotPassword':
        email_subject = os.environ['PASSWORD_RESET_EMAIL_SUBJECT']
        email_message = os.environ['PASSWORD_RESET_EMAIL_MESSAGE']
        required_placeholders = ['codeParameter']
    else:
        return event
    validate_placeholders(email_message, required_placeholders)
    event['response']['emailSubject'] = replace_placeholders(email_subject, attributes)
    event['response']['emailMessage'] = replace_placeholders(email_message, attributes)
    # START TEMP CODE
    logger.info("Event [END]: %s", event)
    # END TEMP CODE
    return event

Here's an incoming event
{'version': '1', 'region': 'eu-west-1', 'userPoolId': 'xxx', 'userName': 'xxx', 'callerContext': {'awsSdkVersion': 'aws-sdk-unknown-unknown', 'clientId': 'CLIENT_ID_NOT_APPLICABLE'}, 'triggerSource': 'CustomMessage_AdminCreateUser', 'request': {'userAttributes': {'sub': 'xxx', 'email_verified': 'true', 'cognito:user_status': 'FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD', 'email': 'xxx.xxx@gmail.com'}, 'codeParameter': '{####}', 'linkParameter': '{##Click Here##}', 'usernameParameter': '{username}'}, 'response': {'smsMessage': None, 'emailMessage': None, 'emailSubject': None}}

And here's an outgoing event
 {'version': '1', 'region': 'eu-west-1', 'userPoolId': 'xxx', 'userName': 'xxx', 'callerContext': {'awsSdkVersion': 'aws-sdk-unknown-unknown', 'clientId': 'CLIENT_ID_NOT_APPLICABLE'}, 'triggerSource': 'CustomMessage_AdminCreateUser', 'request': {'userAttributes': {'sub': 'xxx', 'email_verified': 'true', 'cognito:user_status': 'FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD', 'email': 'justin.worrall@gmail.com'}, 'codeParameter': '{####}', 'linkParameter': '{##Click Here##}', 'usernameParameter': '{username}'}, 'response': {'smsMessage': None, 'emailMessage': 'Your username is xxx.xxx@xxx.com and your temporary password is {####}', 'emailSubject': 'Welcome to XXX!'}}

The response seems to be populated okay, but as before, Cognito will use the response emailSubject but not the response emailMessage
I've been careful to -

populate placeholders for usernameParameter and codeParameter; I understand these are required in the AdminCreateUser case

pass the temporary password through as {####}; I understand Cognito populates it after the handler has been run


There is some conflicting advice on the web about URI- encoding the username, but I've found this makes no difference either
Any idea what's up?
It would be super helpful if Cognito logged why it was rejecting subject/message templates, but I can't find out how to intercept such log messages either
Thank you

So this is quite possibly the worst thing I have ever had to debug with AWS, which is saying something.
I like Cognito because it has a lot of utility but honestly I think the interface was designed by a bunch of monkeys on crack. Identity pools are bad enough but this whole AdminCreateUser CustomMessage stuff really takes the biscuit.
So I am going to write the definitive guide to getting this working in the hope that no-one else has to treat this sorry path again. Because in a couple of places I seemed to be getting Cognito errors for which there didn't seem to be any Google results.

The job of a Cognito custom message handler is to insert placeholders into a custom message. Read that carefully. Not placeholder values, but the placeholders themselves.
And not just any placeholders! You can't just use {username} or {code}. No! Cognito has its own placeholders it wants you to use, defined in event.usernameParameter, event.codeParameter and event.linkParameter. The values contained in these fields are the ones that must be inserted into your custom email template.
AdminCreateUser requires the insertion of usernameParameter and codeParameter placeholders. At the time of writing, Cognito seems to be using {username} and {####} for these. So a valid email message body might look at follows -
Your username is {username} and your temp password is {####}

If your email template doesn't look something like the above, it's not going to work.

A word on logging.
If Cognito decides to reject your template, and send the default template instead, it will do so completely silently. No Cloudwatch message, no nothing. Nada. Zip.
This is just the worst.

Where do the {username} and {code} values come from, you ask?
Again, don't be tempted to insert the values yourself as part of the placeholder code. The handler's job is to insert the correct placeholders only! Cognito will insert values after the handler has finished its job.
Various internet sources will tell you that "username comes from event.userName" or "username comes from event.request.userAttributes". Ignore them, and ignore the temptation to override event.userName if (as in my case, initially) the field value doesn't look like an email. Again, Cognito will insert values for username and code outside the scope of the handler, and the values in event can't influence this, they are there for record only.
Various internet sources will suggest you need to urlquote the value of username. Again, ignore them. You are not inserting values in the template.

Despite having a template which appeared to correctly formed (with placeholders for {username} and {####}, I was still getting some kind of message (sadly not saved for posterity) saying something like "the value of your username is inconsistent / doesn't match"
At this point I started looking at the logged event messages and noticed the event.userName looked much more like a UUID and not an email. This despite the fact that in my Cognito UserPool definition, I had UsernameAttributes: [email] defined.
After a conversation with ChatGPT, it seemed that this wasn't enough to have the UserPool fully recognise email as the user definition field. In fact you also need to define UsernameConfiguration: {CaseSensitive: false} in order for the email to be "fully recognised".
And lo and behold, adding this to the UserPool definition finally caused the custom email to be sent, with the placeholders correctly populated. But the value of event.userName in incoming handler messages was still in UUID format.
I have no idea.

Here is my UserPool config  -
   "AppUserPool": {
      "Properties": {
        "AutoVerifiedAttributes": [
          "email"
        ],
        "LambdaConfig": {
          "CustomMessage": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
              "AppCustomMessageFunction",
              "Arn"
            ]
          },
          "PostAuthentication": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
              "AppUserCallbackFunction",
              "Arn"
            ]
          },
          "PostConfirmation": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
              "AppUserCallbackFunction",
              "Arn"
            ]
          },
          "PreAuthentication": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
              "AppUserCallbackFunction",
              "Arn"
            ]
          },
          "PreSignUp": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
              "AppUserCallbackFunction",
              "Arn"
            ]
          }
        },
        "Policies": {
          "PasswordPolicy": {
            "MinimumLength": 8,
            "RequireLowercase": true,
            "RequireNumbers": true,
            "RequireSymbols": true,
            "RequireUppercase": true
          }
        },
        "Schema": [
          {
            "AttributeDataType": "String",
            "Mutable": true,
            "Name": "email",
            "Required": true,
            "StringAttributeConstraints": {
              "MinLength": "1"
            }
          }
        ],
        "UsernameAttributes": [
          "email"
        ],
        "UsernameConfiguration": {
          "CaseSensitive": false
        }
      },
      "Type": "AWS::Cognito::UserPool"
    }

And here is my handler code -
import logging, os

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def replace_placeholders(message, template_values):
    for key, value in template_values.items():
        message = message.replace(f'{{{key}}}', value)
    return message

def validate_placeholders(message, required_placeholders):
    for placeholder in required_placeholders:
        if f'{{{placeholder}}}' not in message:
            raise RuntimeError(f"Missing required placeholder: {{{placeholder}}}")

def handler(event, context):
    logger.info("Event [START]: %s", event)
    template_values = {'username': event['request']['usernameParameter'],
                       'code': event['request']['codeParameter']}
    if event['triggerSource'] == 'CustomMessage_AdminCreateUser':
        email_subject = os.environ['TEMP_PASSWORD_EMAIL_SUBJECT']
        email_message = os.environ['TEMP_PASSWORD_EMAIL_MESSAGE']
        required_placeholders = ['username', 'code']
    elif event['triggerSource'] == 'CustomMessage_ForgotPassword':
        email_subject = os.environ['PASSWORD_RESET_EMAIL_SUBJECT']
        email_message = os.environ['PASSWORD_RESET_EMAIL_MESSAGE']
        required_placeholders = ['code']
    else:
        return event
    validate_placeholders(email_message, required_placeholders)
    event['response']['emailSubject'] = replace_placeholders(email_subject, template_values)
    event['response']['emailMessage'] = replace_placeholders(email_message, template_values)
    logger.info("Event [END]: %s", event)
    return event

You're welcome :)

I should add. Unlike most every other Lambda handler, Cognito handlers are required to return JSON, else some kind of JSON error will occur. This seems clear enough in the above example, where the templating stuff needs to be passed further down the line, but less clear in other Cognito callback examples. In fact anything in the LambdaConfig property of a UserPool will need to return JSON. And worth noting in passing that these handlers are called in a sync fashion, not async

Wow. Thanks for sharing your findings in such detail! I ended up putting the usernameParamter in the template but hiding it via CSS. BTW I guess you know that you still can access the event['request']['userAttributes']['email'] user properties if that helps.
